# Swift: How to Reload Content Blocker

Tags: json, swift, safari-extension, ios-extensions

I'm using the "Content Blocker Extension" in my project, and have been informed that I have to call `SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier()` in my main app to reload the data in `blockerList.json.`

But I don't really know HOW I should call it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When there is need (like when the user changes something) to reload the data from blockerList.json you call:

```
SFContentBlockerManager.reloadContentBlocker(withIdentifier: "your-blocker-id", completionHandler: { error in
    if let error = error {
        // do something here when an error is thrown
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
})
```